# How to apply class as per the Count of the li tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the structure of the HTML

```
<div class="submenu">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If there are three UL the the I want to add **three-col** class.
two UL then **two-col**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Jquery, `$(".submenu > ul").size()` gives you the count.

This will set the class on the div with class submenu:

```
var count = $(".submenu > ul").size();
if(count == 3)
{
  $(".submenu").addClass("three-col");
}
else if(count == 2)
{
  $(".submenu").addClass("two-col");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
  $(".submenu").addClass(
    ($(".submenu ul").size() == 2) ? "two-col" : "three-col"
  );
});
```